# Assigning Roles to external User in Keycloak Using User SPI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have implemented User Storage SPI in Keycloak using Spring Boot example given in official docs. For External data store i have used Sql Server. The Keycloak User SPI is working fine to authenticate the user present in Sql Server and I can get successfully access token using Keycloak REST API.

Now I want to assign a keycloak role to the external user and I am not sure how to do it.

If further details are required regarding the question then feel free to ask.

Here is the User Federation details that i've registered:

**User Federation:**

[image: User Federation]

> Note: During the login process using keycloak User SPI, these functions are getting called getUserById() & getUserByEmail()/getUserByUserName()

Comment: Have you simply tried it? If your SPI works as you say, Keycloak should handle the mapping for you. No need to implement anything at all.

Comment: Yes, the SPI is working and authenticating user too but not saving a user in user store inside keycloak, i've gone through User SPI docs 2,3 times but couldn't find anything regarding it.

Comment: Do you see the user under "Users" in Keycloak or is the user missing after successful authentication? If so you are missing an implementation detail. Have you implemented the `UserStorageProvider`?

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak is storing your user data under FED_* tables. If you want to map roles you can override method which will be called by keycloak in your UserAdapter (AbstractUserAdapterFederatedStorage):

```
override fun getRoleMappingsInternal(): MutableSet<RoleModel> {
  val roles = mutableSetOf<RoleModel>()
  val myProviderRoles: List<String> = user.roles
  for (it in myProviderRoles) {
    realm.getClientsStream(-1, -1).forEach { client ->
        val role = client.getRole(it)
        if (role != null) roles += role
    }
  }
  return roles
}
```

Then when you are creating adapter fill in the roles you want:

```
override fun createAdapter(myUser: MyUser, session: KeycloakSession, realm: RealmModel, model: UserStorageProviderModel): UserModel {
    myUser.roles = repositoryRoles.getUserRoles(myUser.id).map { it.name }
    return UserAdapter(myUser, session, realm, model)
}
```